# How to recall a loop after it runs and its condition is reset

Tags: c#

Not sure if I've numbed my mind trying to figure this but I'm trying to get a loop to trigger again after it runs by changing its condition in a later branch of code based on user input. Here's the code:

```
int moveend = 1;
for (int move = 0; move < moveend; move++)
{   
    if (move < 1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a direction to move\n");

        //forloop that allows the output to cycle the legth of array and branch to a new line on 4th output
        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
        {
          //for loop code
        }
        //This is the code i'm using to re trigger the previous loop with "move = 0"
        ConsoleKeyInfo kb = Console.ReadKey();
        if (kb.Key == ConsoleKey.UpArrow)
        {
            map[7, 1] = 1;
            map[11, 1] = 0;
            move = 0;
            Console.WriteLine("FIre");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("END");
    }
}
```

I'm not sure why it is that I can see the "Fire" with this code but it doesn't loop again despite the loop condition being reset within the loop. I expected it to reprint the loop info with the updated array coordinates `map[7, 1] = 1; map[11, 1] = 0;` but it doesn't. Am I overlooking something or is there something I'm missing about loops?

Comment: After you set move to 0, the for iteration will execute  `move++`, so the next run, move will not be < 1. You could set move to -1 or reverse the logic and remove the increase in the for and instead only increase move when needed.

Comment: BTW, value of move variable will increment to 1 at the end of the iteration even though you set it to zero. So as move >= moveend , your loop will terminate.

Comment: Even if you set move=0, the next run of the outer loop will have move=1 because of move++, so the if statement will be false

Comment: Weird thing happened when I entered the code but moveend is 1.

Comment: moveend is 1 but when comparing move<moveend the condition fails as both it checks 1<1 which is false and hence the loop terminates. Either set move=-1 so that when it increments move++ , the value of move becomes 0 and then 0<1 can enter the loop.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that you set `move` to 0, but it is already zero.

The loop can loosely be translated to this:

```
int move = 0;
while (move < moveend)
{
    ... rest of your code
    move++;
}
```

So `move` is 0 the whole time throughout the loop, and is increased at the end, and then it is no longer `< moveend`.

To keep running the loop, perhaps you don't want a `for` loop at all?

```
bool keepRunning = true;
while (keepRunning)
{
    keepRunning = false;

    ... rest of your code
    if (...)
        keepRunning = true; // force another run through the loop
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why are you doing it like that I think this might help you to accomplish your task

```
bool dirtyBool = true;
while(dirtyBool)
{   
    if (move < 1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a direction to move\n");

        //forloop that allows the output to cycle the legth of array and branch to a new line on 4th output
        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
        {
          //for loop code
        }
        //This is the code i'm using to re trigger the previous loop with "move = 0"
        ConsoleKeyInfo kb = Console.ReadKey();
        if (kb.Key == ConsoleKey.UpArrow)
        {
            map[7, 1] = 1;
            map[11, 1] = 0;
            move = 0;
            dirtyBool=false;
            Console.WriteLine("FIre");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        dirtyBool=false;
        Console.WriteLine("END");
    }
}
```

I have added a variable dirtyBool of type Bool which will make loop it again. Modify the code according to your usablility